# Benchmarking memory consumption of Firefox vs Chrome in webdriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, firefox, selenium

I am trying the maximize the number of browsers that I can run a script on on my computer. How would I figure out how much memory consumption each Chrome or Firefox process is taking when I launch `webdriver`. For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('www.yahoo.com')

# - or - #

from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('www.yahoo.com')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instantiating `webdriver.Chrome` or `webdriver.Firefox` spawns at least one
other process, so to get an estimate of total memory consumption it might be
easiest to measure total system memory available before and after launching the
processes. How to find the total memory used depends on your OS; the [psutils
module](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) supports Linux, Windows, OSX,
FreeBSD and Sun Solaris.

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import contextlib
import time
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as UI
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
import psutil

def worker(browsername, args, N):
    start_mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
    Driver = getattr(webdriver, browsername)
    drivers = [Driver(*args) for i in range(N)]
    end_mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
    for driver in drivers:
        driver.quit()
    return end_mem.used - start_mem.used

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 10
    pool = mp.Pool(1)

    for driver, args in [('Firefox', ()),
                         ('Chrome', ()), 
                         ('PhantomJS', ('phantomjs',))]:
        used = pool.apply(worker, [driver, args, N])
        print('{:>10}: {}'.format(driver, used))
        time.sleep(5)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

yields

```
   Firefox: 1072779264
    Chrome: 1124683776
 PhantomJS: 102670336
```

So it appears [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) uses about 10x less memory.

Technical note: There is no reliable way to force a Python process to relinquish memory it has used *back to the OS* [short of terminating the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python/1316799#1316799). So I used multiprocessing to spawn each test in a separate process so when it terminates the memory used is freed. The `pool.apply()` blocks until `worker` ends.